# Getting Linux error while installing phpmyadmin in centos

Tags: linux, centos, yum

When i am trying `yum install phpmyadmin` then i get this error

```
Error: Package: php-gd-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Installed: php-common-5.5.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.0-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch has missing requires of yum-plugin-fastestmirror
```

What do i need to do to fix that error

UPDATE:

Then i get this

```
Repository epel is listed more than once in the configuration
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:3.5.8.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-gd >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6 for package: php-gd-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-3.el6 will be installed

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-gd-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 from base
    php-php-gettext-1.0.11-3.el6.noarch from epel
    phpMyAdmin-3.5.8.1-1.el6.noarch from epel
```

Comment: Have you tried using "--skip-broken to work around the problem"?

Comment: @RobbieMckennie then i get this eror. See updated ques

Comment: do you really need to use php-5.5? Could you show output of the following command # yum list installed | grep php

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because you have a newer version of PHP - specifically the `php-common` package - installed from the `remi-test` repo than the `php-gd` package can deal with. The easiest way to resolve the initial problem is to remove the `remi-test` repo, downgrade to the version of php-common provided in the base repo, then re-run the `yum install phpmyadmin` command.

Comment: how can i remoeve remi-test , repo and how can i downgrade the php-common

Comment: How did you install the remi-test repo? If you isntalled a package for it like epel-release for the epel repo, remove that package. If you simply created the repo file, remove that file.

Answer (score 0):

> ** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows: yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch has missing requires of
>   yum-plugin-fastestmirror

Yum version 3.2.49 requires yum-plugin-fastermirror pacakge. It seems like it is missing.

Can you run `rpm -qa | grep fastestmirror` and update your answer. If nothing appears, install the yum-plugin-fastestmirror via rpm directly.

There is a link where you can get directly the rpm http://zid-lux1.uibk.ac.at/linux/rpm2html/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch.html

Comment: I installed that and again i get the same error. `rpm -qa | grep fastestmirror
yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch`

Comment: This is a problem, but it's unrelated to the immediate issue.